# Where is the Error in this get-HTML-from-Url-Function?

Tags: java, android

I have this function:

```
public String getUrl(String url) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String html = "";
            try {
                    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
                    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

                    // Pass local context as a parameter
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);

                    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(in));
                    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            str.append(line);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    html = str.toString();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
                    return html;
            }
    }
```

The problem is, that these function never returns any char (i've tried it out with google.de) . Sadly the Result is always empty.

Thx for Help

Answer (score 0):

My guess (I can only guess with the information you provide):

You forgot the Internet permission in the manifest.

Comment: Closed. It was the easyest problem you can think about: 1) i forgott the Internet Permission and Second; My Phone lost Connection (I'am asheamed of myself). Thank you, for your help :-)